# C# QuickSort algorithm

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, quicksort

Today I decided to learn how Quick sort algorithm work. I studied some examples and watched a few YouTube videos on the matter. 
So, after that I decided to try and write it down. I did use some pointers from a YouTube channel that I find extremely helpful.

When I try to run the program however, I get a "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException" and I'm unable to figure why.
I will appreciate if anyone could help me.

```
private static void QuickSort(int[] numbers, int beginning, int end)
    {
        int pivotLoc = 0;
        if(beginning < end)
        {
            Partition(numbers, beginning, end, pivotLoc);
            QuickSort(numbers, beginning, pivotLoc - 1);
            QuickSort(numbers, pivotLoc + 1, end);
        }
    }
    private static void Partition(int[] numbers, int beginning, int end,int pivotLoc)
    {
        int left = beginning; 
        int right = end;
        int temp;
        pivotLoc = left;
        while (true)
        {
            while(numbers[pivotLoc] <= numbers[right] && pivotLoc != right)
            {
                right--;
            }
            if(pivotLoc == right)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(numbers[pivotLoc] > numbers[right])
            {
                temp = numbers[right];
                numbers[right] = numbers[pivotLoc];
                numbers[pivotLoc] = temp;
                pivotLoc = right; 
            }
            while (numbers[pivotLoc] >= numbers[left] && pivotLoc != left)
            {
                left++;
            }
            if(pivotLoc == left)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(numbers[pivotLoc] < numbers[left]) 
            {
                temp = numbers[left];
                numbers[left] = numbers[pivotLoc];
                numbers[pivotLoc] = temp;
                pivotLoc = left;
            }                    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ask that at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ here you'll probably  get a _why isn't this code working?_ close

Comment: StackOverflowException often means something's calling itself recursively without stopping until the call stack is full.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping it in the debugger?

Comment: I really think you are missing the **return value** of `Partition(...)`. Perhaps you should have a look back at [Wikipedia - Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz You were right. Thank you!